# Delta method on sequences

Tags: probability

We have $ \left\{X_n \right\}, \left\{Y_n \right\}$ sequences of random variables.

Also $a_n \left(X_n-Y_n \right)\xrightarrow[d] {} Z$, and $X_n,Y_n\xrightarrow[d]{}\theta$.
Let $g$ be continuously differentiable at $x=\theta$.

I have to prove that $a_n \left(g(X_n)-g(Y_n) \right)\xrightarrow[d] {} g'(\theta)Z$.

Doing a Taylor expansion for $g$ around $\theta$, we get:

$g(X_n)=g(\theta)+g'(\theta^*_{nx})(X_n-\theta)$ and $g(Y_n)=g(\theta)+g'(\theta^*_{ny})(Y_n-\theta)$,

where we have $|\theta^*_{nx}-\theta|\leq |X_n-\theta|$ and $|\theta^*_{ny}-\theta|\leq |Y_n-\theta|$.

Hence $a_n \left(g(X_n)-g(Y_n) \right)= a_n(g'(\theta^*_{nx})X_n-g'(\theta^*_{ny})Y_n)+ a_n\theta (g'(\theta^*_{nx})-g'(\theta^*_{ny}))$. However I'm stuck here. If I was able to somehow substitute $\theta^*_{nx}$ and $\theta^*_{ny}$ for an equal sequence, I would be able to prove what I want.

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: It's usually easier to think in terms of characteristic functions for that convergence - maybe that's something to look at here.

Comment: @MattB. thank you for your interest on this question. Could please elaborate a bit, on how it may be easier to think in terms of characteristic functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual reflex in those questions is to use the characteristic function, and prove its simple convergence.

For instance, $\phi(a_n (g(X_n)-g(Y_n)) = E[\exp(it \times a_n (g(X_n)-g(Y_n)))] $

Then with the Taylor expansion you mention, $g(X_n)-g(Y_n) = g(\theta) + g'(\theta)(X_n - \theta) +o(X_n - \theta) - (g(\theta) + g'(\theta)(Y_n - \theta) +o(Y_n- \theta)) $ which then yields $\phi(a_n (g(X_n)-g(Y_n)) = E[\exp(it\times g'(\theta) \times a_n (X_n-Y_n))]$ and you know by hypothesis that $E[\exp(it  \times a_n (X_n-Y_n))]$ converge towards $\phi_Z(t)$, so you recognize the limit above to be $\phi_{g'(\theta)Z}$.

The exact reason why you can drop the $o$ should be thought of in more details.

More details here: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%99s_continuity_theorem)

Comment: Thanks Matt B. for your answer. Side note: Isn't your expression inside the small o wrong?

Comment: Indeed it should read $X_n - \theta$. Let me edit that.