# Little O notation calculus

Tags: probability

Imagine we have $a_n(X_n-\theta)-a_n(Y_n-\theta)\xrightarrow[d]{}Z$.

Also, $a_n\xrightarrow[]{}\infty$, and $X_n, Y_n\xrightarrow[p]{}\theta$.

$o(g(x))$ is an expression that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{o(g(x))}{g(x)}=0$. (Little 'o' notation)

Can I say that $a_no(X_n-\theta)-a_no(Y_n-\theta)\xrightarrow[d]{}0$?

We also know that $o(X_n-\theta)= (X_n-\theta)\cdot o(1)$, and $o(1) \supset o\left((X_n-\theta)^k\right)$, for $k\geq1$.

I think we can safely assume that $X_n,Y_n$ converge with the same speed, since from the initial assumption that gives $a_n(X_n-Y_n)\xrightarrow[d]{}Z$.

So, my doubt lies in, when we disrupt the balance in the speed convergence,  how can we be sure if, since it's possible, to prove $a_n(X_n-\theta)\cdot \phi_n-a_n(Y_n-\theta)\cdot \psi_n\xrightarrow[d]{}0$, where $\phi_n$ would be a sequnce that would decrease very slowly to zero, and $\psi_n$ would decrease very fast. I'm just trying to assume the worst case scenerio, if that is possible in this situation...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevance of probabilistic concepts to the question is not very clear (for example, when you say that $X_n\to\theta$, in which sense? and, in the definition of $o$, which limit should one consider?) but it happens that already the deterministic version of the result you suggest, fails--hence there is no chance its probabilistic counterpart would hold.

Example: $x_n=1/n$, $y_n=1/n-1/n^4$, $a_n=n^3$, $\theta=0$, choose $x'_n=1/n^2$ and $y'_n=0$, then every hypothesis is met, in particular $a_n(x_n-\theta)-a_n(y_n-\theta)=1/n\to0$, $x'_n\in o(x_n)$ and $y'_n\in o(y_n)$, but $a_nx'_n-a_ny'_n=n$ does not converge to $0$.

Comment: Many thanks for your interest in this question. I've edited the question. In the little o notation, we should use the usual calculus convergence definition, and $X_n, Y_n$ the convergence in probability. This question came up when I was trying to answer one of my own questions... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868355/delta-method-on-sequences

Comment: Your acceptance strategy is slightly surprising. Do you really consider the accepted answer to your other question is a full solution? I see at least one equal sign which should be... dunno what exactly but not an equal sign anyway...

Comment: if it's not too much trouble, could please you provide a better one for that question?

Comment: Would it be morally incorrect to 'unaccept' an answer and then ask you again? 

Or I could just create another question where I would specifically state that to solve I could not use the characteristic function. But is this also incorrect? 

Either way, I thank you for your answer to this question.

Comment: Your problem, (old) man. :-)

Comment: Yes it is... I guess I'll just have to think about it by myself for a while. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify lets let $f_n(x) = o(g(x))$. In this case, $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{o(g(x))}{g(x)}=0$ implies *pointwise* convergence of $f_n$ to zero for all $x$. These $x$ are fixed, so in reality $f_n(x)=o(1)\;\;\forall x$ . Thus, your hypothesis becomes:

$a_nf_n(X_n-\theta) -a_nf_n(Y_n-\theta) \xrightarrow[d]{}0$

In order for this to be true, we need to know how fast the $a_n$ grow. Since the $a_n$ allow convergence in distribution, $a_n=O(1/X_n)\;\;\text{or}\;\; O(1/Y_n)$ Thus, if the $X_n$ or $Y_n$ grow without bound, then $a_n\rightarrow 0$ if the $X_n$ or $Y_n$ approach a non-zero constant, then $a_n=O(1)$. In either case, your $a_n$ will not make $a_nf_n > o(1)$.

Therefore, yes, you can conclude that the value difference of the functions of the sequences will converge (in probability) to zero.

Comment: Many thanks for your interest in this question. I was reading your answer and I noticed that there is some information missing in the original question...I'm very sorry. I'm going to edit it.

Comment: Are you using the big 'o' notation in its usual mathematical sense in your answer? Or did you mean to use a little 'o'?